# How to handle multiple different in array Response type with Retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit2, pojo

I have a response with array and some feilds, for few fields that getting different types, please look into below JSONObject.

```
{
"access_key": "fsdf7767sdfsdkjnkjsdf83",
"places": [
    {
        "attraction_names": "Taj Mahal",
        "visitors_count_per_year": 1598464,
        "address": "Agra, India",
        "images": [
            {
                "image": "http://www.tajmahal.gov.in/images/View_taj_mahal/night1.jpg"
            },
            {
                "image": "http://charismaticplanet.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/Original-Tajmahal.jpg"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "attraction_names": "Tanjavur Temple",
        "visitors_count_per_year": 351321321,
        "address": "Tamil Nadu, India",
        "images": [""]
    },{
        "attraction_names": "CharMinar",
        "visitors_count_per_year": 963252,
        "address": "Agra, India",
        "images": [
            {
                "image": "https://www.southtourism.in/assets/uploads/pages/charminar.jpg"
            },
            {
                "image": "https://thumbnails.trvl-media.com/Zz4GovwBjpcnWi5tytMvwOZ3bm8=/768x432/images.trvl-media.com/media/content/shared/images/travelguides/destination/6053329/Hyderabad-And-Vicinity-68046.jpg"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

}

How to handle the second item in the array, where I'm using pojo class as response on retrofit, when the response getting it into OnFailure Method

Comment: I'm facing the same issue

Comment: http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

Comment: @NileshRathod is this standard, getting back old style to retrieve data from HashMap

Comment: @NileshRathod I tried using jsonschema2pojo.org, response was getting null, I try to solve as changing varible in pojo with actual key value, then its going to OnFailure mwthod in retrofit

Comment: I think you have to convert into map, check the type of "images" and map accordingly. Take a look https://stackoverflow.com/a/41464252/5689605